# WKWebView continuously breaking constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I've created a `UIViewController` with two distinct sections. There's a `headerView` and a `contentView` in which I want to add a `WKWebView` instance.

Since I'm creating the `WKWebView` programmatically, I've got to add the constraints in a likewise fashion.

Here's how I add them:

```
-(void)loadYoutubeVideoWithID:(NSString *)videoID {
    if (![self webView]){
        /* Create WebView */
        WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];

        /* Set Delegate */
        [webView setNavigationDelegate:self];

        /* Set Local Property */
        [self setWebView:webView];

        /* Add to content view */
        [self.contentView addSubview:webView];

        /* Create Constraints */
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[webView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView)]];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[webView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView)]];
    }
}
```

Despite adding constraints, I can't get them to be respected. I've tried up to four different variations of these constraints based on other answers across StackExchange, but my `WKWebView` never resizes when the screen rotates.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

I'm not sure how to fix this. I've got the output log linked [here](http://pastebin.com/nNM2vpz9) (It's rather long) concerning the constraints breaking, but it's not of much use to me.

Does anyone know why I am unable to resize the `WKWebView`?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit: *This also happens with a regular UIImageView, when used in place of the WKWebView***

Answer (score 6):

Solving this problem is rather simple. It requires that you add the line:

`[webView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`

After initializing your `WKWebView` instance, or any other `UIView` that you wish to resize within the content view. Here is the fixed example:

```
-(void)loadYoutubeVideoWithID:(NSString *)videoID {
    if (![self webView]){
        /* Create WebView */
        WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        /* Ensure Constraints remain when resizing the View */
        [webView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        /* Set Delegate */
        [webView setNavigationDelegate:self];

        /* Set Local Property */
        [self setWebView:webView];

        /* Add to content view */
        [self.contentView addSubview:webView];

        /* Create Constraints */
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[webView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView)]];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[webView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView)]];
    }
}
```

I hope others find this instructional.